# For loop in a function - not iterating through string

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I'm looking to take in two strings via user input and to call a function to match each character from the first string to that of the second string, and count them. So String 1 = bad and String 2 = bed would return a count of 2 characters matched

```
def occurrences(text1, text2):

    count = 0

    for c in firstword :
        if c == secondword :
            count += 1
            return True
    return False


firstword = input("Enter first word")

secondword = input("Enter second word")

occurrences(firstword, secondword)
```

Passing the two strings into the function returns false, even if they're exactly the same word. Just wondering where I'm going wrong with the for loop here, why is the if statement not matching the strings and counting.
Thanks

Comment: ```return sum(1 for i in text1 if i in text2)```?

Comment: jus change == to in `if a in b` instead of `if a == b` it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for c in firstword :
    if c == secondword :
```

You're iterating over the first string character by character (`for c in firstword`), and you match that one character to the *entire* second string `secondword`. Not to mention that:

- you're using the outer variables `firstword` and `secondword` instead of the function parameters `text1` and `text2`
- your function only returns `True` or `False`, at no point does it even attempt to return a count
- you `return True` right on the first match, if there ever was one, so it could never progress beyond 1

To compare two strings character by character, you need to iterate both string in parallel. The best way to do that is [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
count = 0
for c1, c2 in zip(text1, text2):
    if c1 == c2:
        count += 1
```

Which can be made into a one-liner with `sum`:

```
def occurrences(text1, text2):
    return sum(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in zip(text1, text2))
```

---

Silly bonus round, if you want to be really fancy and *functional* about it:

```
from operator import eq
from itertools import starmap

def occurrences(text1, text2):
    return sum(starmap(eq, zip(text1, text2)))
```

Comment: Ughhh, that totally explains it, I thought I was approaching it totally wrong. Thanks for your explanation !

Comment: Woah! I thought it was the other way round. Now I understand. Thanks

Comment: The "fancy" way rather looks indeed silly to me. Zipping them just so you need starmap to unpack them? I'd just do `sum(map(eq, text1, text2))`.

Comment: @don't Eh, true, overcomplicated that a bit, didn't I?

Answer (score 2):

In `function` when you arrive on `return`, the function is ending so when you want counting and end of `for-loop` return your counter don't set `return` in `for-loop`.
try this:

```
def occurrences(text1, text2):
    count = 0
    for c in firstword :
        if c in secondword :
            count += 1
    return count

firstword = input("Enter first word : ")
secondword = input("Enter second word : ")
occurrences(firstword, secondword)
```

output:

```
Enter first word : bad
Enter second word : bed
2
```

Comment: Thankyou! I knew I was doing something dumb but didn't know where I was going wrong. Another dumb question, I see you changed my `if c == secondword` to `if c in secondword` When I did == did that mean it was trying to match the single character of c with the entire `secondword` as a string?

Comment: @RenaissanceMan, in your code you chech `char` == `string` this is wrong, for checking that string have char using `in` like this  : `char` in `string`